# Doctrine- one of associations doesn't work proper

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have problem with associations in Doctrine 2
I have two associations which look the same. One works fine, the second one work in weird way. I'll explain it a bit later.

Here is my main entity- Product:

```
**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="category_index", columns={"category_id"}),
 *      @ORM\Index(name="partner_index", columns={"partner_id"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var Partner
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Partner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="partner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $partnerId;
}
```

Category Entity:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $categoryName;
}
```

Partner Entity:

```
/**
 * Partner
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="partner")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Partner
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

As you can see I have two identical associations:
Product#categoryId
Product#partnerId

The first one- categoryId works as it should, but the second one- partnerId doesn't:

First thing I noticed is that Doctrine create proxy class with Partner Entity,
   while Category Entity doesn't need proxy class to work, so one of
   this doesn't work proper.I just started with Doctrine so I might be
   wrong.

I have 4 records in Partner table. When I try to modify Product
   record manually, in partner_id field I can't set 1-4, I can set
   something like this:

```
(empty)
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 3
4 - 4
(empty)
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 3
4 - 4
```

First time I see something like this.

And the last thing I noticed:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT pp.name, p.id
    FROM Application\Entity\Product AS p
    LEFT JOIN Application\Entity\Partner AS pp WITH p.partner_id = pp.id GROUP by p.partner_id
');
$items = $query->getResult();
```

Shows me error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 148 near 'partner_id =': Error: Class Application\Entity\Product has no field or association named partner_id in
```

Thanks for any help and tips.

**Edit**
So, the question is. Why does Doctrine create proxy class for Partner Entity, but not for Category?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Doctrine will only create proxies when functionality for the entity it belongs to is used.

You can also manually generate the proxies using the command line tools.

About the error:
You should use partnerId instead of partner_id. Partner_id is the name of your database column, not of the attribute defined in your Product entity.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT pp.name, p.id
    FROM Application\Entity\Product AS p
    LEFT JOIN Application\Entity\Partner AS pp WITH p.partnerId = pp.id GROUP by p.partnerId
');
$items = $query->getResult();
```

Have a good look at the DQL documentation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Maybe it will give you some extra insights about the difference between SQL and DQL.